# how to execute methods in ngoninit one after another

Tags: javascript, angular, constructor, angular-reactive-forms, ngoninit

I have 4 methods in ngoninit two methods form getting data from api and other two are to load that data on page load
example:

```
ngOnInit(){
getname();
getsubjects();
loadname(); 
loadsubjects();
}
/*this loadname to load reactive forms which is declared in constructor
when I am running this I am getting form value as empty If I put load name() in change or click then values are loading to the form am I missing something here conceptual wise anything or any suggestions ?*/
```

Comment: Call the methods within the `subscribe` block for you async code that is calling the API.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

> how to execute methods in ngoninit one after another

As @Optimal says, consider using `concat()` to do this in combination with what I suggest...

> when I am running this I am getting form value as empty If I put load name() in change or click then values are loading to the form am I missing something here conceptual wise anything or any suggestions ?

**Observables** are used to communicate with backend api services using HTTP from Angular, as data arrives at the frontend *asynchronously*, and to "capture" this data as soon as it arrives you use `subscribe()`

[Reference](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response) to the very clear and helpful Angular doc that explains this

My possible solution

```
ngOnInit() {

   // 'name' is captured as soon as it "arrives" from the api service
   // 'this.name' is the local (variable) destination of the requested data
   getname().subscribe(name => this.name = name)

   // same for subjects
   getsubjects().subscribe(subjects => this.subjects = subjects)

   // ...
}
```

should work **but it depends on how you implemented the get() methods**.
If you can, **please provide the full code for a better answer**

---

I hope I was helpful, let me know how it goes! :)

Comment: This will start execute the requests in order but most of the time (if the order is important) you want to ensure that one request is complete after you start the next one.

Comment: @Optimal please explain better what is the context of the problem and what result you want to achieve because I did not get the question...

Comment: I did not ask the question but with `concat()` you can ensure that the observables are executed in sequence. That is my interpretation of the question.

Comment: @Optimal my bad I thought for a while that you was the author of the question. Ty for the advise, I learn something new because of your answer :) However, I think a question should not be interpreted... if it is, it means something is wrong :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use [concat](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat) to run observables in order.

```
import { concat } from 'rxjs';


ngOnInit(): void {
    concat(getName(), getSubjects(), loadName(), loadSubjects())
    .subscribe();
}
```